# mercurial: Why are some branches displayed as active even though their only head has been merged?

Tags: mercurial

Sometimes a Mercurial branch is still listed as active even though its only head has been merged into the default branch.

Does this indicate that something with the merge has gone wrong? If so, how can it be fixed? Or is my assumed definition of an active branch wrong? Or is this simply a bug in Mercurial?

The behaviour has been reproduced with Mercurial 2.2.2 and 3.1.2.

According to the documentation of `hg branches`,

> a branch is considered active if it contains repository heads.

The help for the `--active` option reads:

> show only branches that have unmerged heads

The described behaviour seems to contradict this definition. The behaviour also makes it more difficult to determine which branches contain unmerged work.

**Note:** This question is *not* about closing branches.

**Update 2**: The last change on the merged branch was a merge in the other direction, i.e. from the default branch into that branch.  The default branch contains changesets after that merge. The merged branch contains changesets prior to that merge. (Those changesets were backported from the default branch and do not affect the merge back to default.)

**Update**: Here is the output of `hg heads` before and after merging branch G into the default branch. Branch G is still shown as active after the merge, even though its only head is a parent of tip.

Before:

```
changeset:   dd6bf181645f
tag:         tip
parent:      cdeadfa94c87

changeset:   8d7d2f948588
branch:      A
parent:      9e938cae8ab4
parent:      05d7f9238e8b

changeset:   05d7f9238e8b
branch:      B
parent:      3716c2aa7115

changeset:   c559516254e3
branch:      C

changeset:   546ef1929720
branch:      D
parent:      0e4b1b0b5c39

changeset:   1fafdf04d1b6
branch:      E
parent:      7219db98b8b8

changeset:   412946912c1e
branch:      F
parent:      cdc91f58ce74

changeset:   c982081fd14d
branch:      G
parent:      f053070c2bc1
parent:      f69beaac6cbd

changeset:   b2bba6063165
branch:      H
parent:      051dc556aeee
parent:      7c43b879fd03

changeset:   831e08094998
branch:      I
parent:      4ec88e66b4b4

changeset:   7d3c95a762f4
branch:      K

changeset:   c4a6154688c3
branch:      L
parent:      07c30ea698cf

changeset:   10ef18617b02
branch:      M
parent:      af4eccd4059c
```

After:

```
changeset:   eb4c4e1b876f
tag:         tip
parent:      dd6bf181645f
parent:      c982081fd14d

changeset:   8d7d2f948588
branch:      A
parent:      9e938cae8ab4
parent:      05d7f9238e8b

changeset:   05d7f9238e8b
branch:      B
parent:      3716c2aa7115

changeset:   c559516254e3
branch:      C

changeset:   546ef1929720
branch:      D
parent:      0e4b1b0b5c39

changeset:   1fafdf04d1b6
branch:      E
parent:      7219db98b8b8

changeset:   412946912c1e
branch:      F
parent:      cdc91f58ce74

changeset:   c982081fd14d
branch:      G
parent:      f053070c2bc1
parent:      f69beaac6cbd

changeset:   b2bba6063165
branch:      H
parent:      051dc556aeee
parent:      7c43b879fd03

changeset:   831e08094998
branch:      I
parent:      4ec88e66b4b4

changeset:   7d3c95a762f4
branch:      K

changeset:   c4a6154688c3
branch:      L
parent:      07c30ea698cf

changeset:   10ef18617b02
branch:      M
parent:      af4eccd4059c
```

Comment: Have you tried with a recent Mercurial version?

Comment: Please show us the output of `hg glog` (with the relevant extension enabled if necessary).

Comment: I have reproduced the behaviour with Mercurial 3.1.2, using the same repository.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your repo history looks like, we cannot help you.  At the very least, show us the output of `hg heads`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I added the output of `hg heads` before and after the merge.

Comment: See Update 2 for some comments on repo history. I attempted to edit down the glog to relevant bits, but it proved very time-consuming and the result would have still been very large and complex.